# Note taking with in-text tagging and specific search feature

Tags: note-taking, information-management

Purpose: I'm looking for an efficient way to organise my notes.

I currently write notes in Evernote by source (for example a note on "Thinking Fast and Slow"). However, I can only tag my notes overall with this app.

I'm looking for something where I can tag (with one or many #) a bullet point or paragraph that I write (this may be about a book or a seminar) within a note.

Then, I can search #heuristics or #dissertation and all relevant points come up.

This part is the feature I'm really struggling to find. I don't want an Evernote type search where it just lists my notes. Rather I'd like something where I can see all bullet points together without going into each individual note. This'll allow me to see my information in the most effective way.

Any recommendations on mobile (iOS) / desktop (Mac OS or Windows) apps or organising systems are much appreciated. Please don't hesitate to recommend paid services - if it's right I'd buy into it.

Answer (score 2):

The [task list plugin](http://zim-wiki.org/manual/Plugins/Task_List.html) for [Zim wiki](http://zim-wiki.org/) does something similar to this. Zim runs on Mac OS X and Windows, but note that there is no mobile version.

It uses tags like this: `@heuristics` and `@dissertation`.

[image: Zim task plugin pane]

[image: Main Zim wiki entry pane]

Comment: I'll give it a go! This is the closest I've seen yet, thank you.